# Get error for "make: Nothing to be done for 'target'"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let me illustrate it with an example.

```
mkdir test
cd test
touch target
make target
```

This will result in: `make: Nothing to be done for 'target'.`

So **make** tells me there is nothing to do. This is because **make** did not find a rule to make `target`, but because the `target` already exists **make** tells me there is nothing to do.

Now, I don't want that. I want **make** to give me an error when it cannot find a rule for `target`, even though the `target` already exists.

I have tried the following:

```
echo '.DEFAULT:
        echo make: *** No rule to make target `$@'.  Stop.
        false'> Makefile
```

But this does not stop the **make** when making multiple targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about it, you would end up with a chicken-and-egg situation (or infinite regress).  Suppose you managed to have a rule that said '*You must have a rule to create* **target** *before it is legitimate*', then you'd have a rule that says '**target** *depends on X*' for some other file *X*.  That's written:

```
target: X
        command to build target from X
```

But then you'd be back to the starting point: you'd also want a rule to create *X*.  How can you do that?  You might have a rule that depends on nothing and magically creates the file *X* when it is needed:

```
X:
        command to build X from nothing
```

Without a rule like that, you have an infinite regress.

So, `make` is designed to ensure that files exist and are up to date.  If a file exists and there are no rules - implicit or explicit - to specify how it is made, then the file is up to date.  What you are seeking to do is not possible.

Comment: Good point, but I'm coping with another problem (not clearly described in my question). Thanks for the response.
I'll create a new question when I've created a simple example to explain the problem.

Comment: Actually there is no chicken-and-the-egg here. You just have to pre-declare all your eggs (much like variable declarations in most languages), Very un-makelike, yes.

Comment: Downvoting. It seems using a phony target will accomplish what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is, that make assumes the target name is also a file which will be build by the given commands.

But sometimes this is not true (e.g. think of "clean").
To tell make that some targets don't build this file, you need to make them "phony". Put the following line into your Makefile:

```
.PHONY: target
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this sounds like a perfectly reasonable (if misguided ;-)) request. You will have to explicitly list every source file with a rule with an empty recipe though.

Here you go:

```
Makefile: ;

.PHONY: dodgy
dodgy%: dodgy; $(error You must provide a rule for $*)
%: dodgy% ;
```

The proof of the pudding:

```
$ rm aa
$ make aa
Makefile:4: *** You must provide a rule for aa.  Stop.
$ touch aa
$ make aa
Makefile:4: *** You must provide a rule for aa.  Stop.
```

Note that the line `Makefile: ;` is necessary. After all, the first thing *make* tries to do is rebuild the Makefile.

Note also that the catch-all pattern rule is non-terminal. This can be a massive performance hit. As the manual says about match anything rules "They are very useful, but it can take a lot of time for make to think about them."